# How to unstack windows

Tags: i3

I pressed <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and my windows flatted into a stack of bars. How can I undo this action or expand them back into their original configuration? The best route I found was to individually select each window and to <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow key</kbd> to split horizontally. Surely there's a trick I'm missing?

Comment: It would greatly help you get an answer if you provided **any** information on your setup such as the actual operating system and window manager you use.

Comment: @JuliePelletier, it's tagged as i3... and this is a basic function of i3 no matter the underlying OS

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can switch between three modes:

- `$mod`+`S` for stacking mode
- `$mod`+`W` for tabbed mode
- `$mod`+`E` for standard mode (aka splith/splitv - the one you seek)

More info on the [User Guide](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_changing_the_container_layout).

Answer (score 3):

Answers here are correct but you need to make sure you're switching modes from the same window where you started it. For a simple test, do the following.

- Open two windows in tiled mode
- `$mod` + `s` on window1
- Switch to window2
- `$mod` + `e` on window2               *# Doesn't work*
- `$mod` + `w` on window2               *# Doesn't work*
- Switch to window1
- `$mod` + `e` on window1               *# Works!*
- `$mod` + `w` on window1               *# Works!*

Answer (score 2):

$mod+e should switch to tiling mode again.

Comment: Tried that to no avail, but perhaps I had to select the whole stack or something first?